# Multi grep to 1 grep? Should i change it and how do i?

Tags: regex, linux, find

This is my final script

```
find -regex "^\..*[^(~$|\.o$|\.exe)]" | grep -v "\.svn" | grep -v ".tab." | grep  -v ".yy." | xargs svn add 2>/dev/null
```

For testing i dont want to add it to svn so i use

```
find -regex "^\..*[^(~$|\.o$|\.exe)]" | grep -v "\.svn" | grep -v ".tab." | grep  -v ".yy."
```

NOTE: I wanted to ignore files that started with '.' (in current and subfolders) but couldnt figure out how so i settled for .svn

I tried removing the extra greps to produce one regex but for the life of me i couldnt get it to ignore .svn (or .FILE) in current and sub folders and i couldnt get it to ignore .tab. or .yy.

One problem is i couldnt understand how to make ^. (ignore if start with?) work. I'm sure one problem is the fact i do .* which will ignore my .tab. rule and i am not sure how to get around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your root problem is that you think you can do this:

```
[^(~$|\.o$|\.exe)]
```

You can't.

In a character class (that's what you have here) you can include (or exclude) individual characters, but you can't write expressions there. The above is equivalent (as far as the regex engine is concerned) to:

```
[^()~$|.oex]
```

I'm on Windows, so I can't give you a tested command, and your post leaves me a little bit puzzled which files you actually want. So this is meant as an indication into the right direction regarding your regex misconception.

Comment: I suspect in this case regex is totally unnecessary. As I belatedly noted in my answer, you can just use -name. Something like `find * ! \( -name *.o -o -name *.exe -o ...\)`, I expect.

Comment: I also think `find` can do it without regex. I'm not very familiar with it, but I saw the major regex error the OP made.

Comment: @Tomalak - yep, you're definitely right about that one. I saw "final script" and mistakenly skimmed over the initial inclusive regex to the ones the OP was explicitly asking about. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

> NOTE: I wanted to ignore files that started with '.' (in current and subfolders) but couldnt figure out how so i settled for .svn
>
> One problem is i couldnt understand how to make ^. (ignore if start with?) work. I'm sure one problem is the fact i do .* which will ignore my .tab. rule and i am not sure how to get around.

The `-regex` test on `find` is applied to the full path, not just the filename. From the man page:

> For example, to match a file named './fubar3', you can use the regular expression '.*bar.' or '.*b.*3', but not 'f.*r3'.

soulmerge's answer provides one way to get all your conditions into the find statement; you could also do it with something like

```
find * -regex 'include-pattern' -a ! \( -regex 'exclude-pattern' [-o 'exclude-pattern2' ...] \)
```

If you want to combine multiple patterns to exclude, whether in your piped greps or in find's regexes, just use an or:

```
grep -v '\.svn\|.tab.\|.yy.'
egrep -v '\.svn|.tab.|.yy.'
```

Note that it's a very, very good idea to use single quotes for regex - you don't want any $ to attempt variable expansion.

Edit:
Those exclude patterns you're suggesting really don't need to be regex. You can get them just with -name, which matches only the actual name, not the whole path.

```
find * -regex 'include-pattern' -a ! \( -name .svn -o -name "*tab*" \)
```

Comment: You should replace `\|` in your grep example with `|\`

Comment: No, that's part of extended regular expressions. I added an egrep line using that.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell `find` to ignore certain folders and their contents with `-prune`. And you don't need a regular expression here, the other find commands are completely sufficient. If you want to be able to handle file names with spaces, I would further use `-print0`. Summing up, this should do what you need:

```
find . \( -name ".*" -prune \) -or \
    -name "*.exe" -or -name "*.o" -or -name "*~" \
    -print0 | xargs -0 svn add
```

Comment: find also supports ! for not, and most versions support "-not" as a synonym (but it's not POSIX).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to achieve but `find -regex '^.*/[^.].*'` should work (matches any non-dot character at the start of the name).

Comment: This isn't going to do what you want. There are only two required characters to get a match - the `/[^.]`. It'll match anything that contains a non-hidden file anywhere in the path, not just in the last component of the path (e.g. /home/username/.svn will match).

Comment: @Jefromi: Doesn't return anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

Grep supports multiple patterns.  E.g.:

```
grep -v -e "\.svn" -e ".tab." -e ".yy."
```